# Task spooler for computing server on Debian

Tags: debian, queue, hpc, cuda

Recently our university has bought an computing server with one multi-core Xeon and 4 powerfull GeForce videocard for lessons on discipline "High perfomance computing with CUDA".

There is Debian Squeeze on it. I'm trying to find a solution for organising task queue (or task spooler) so that students could launch their programs. Since there is only one CPU I guessed that we have to use queue: students' tasks pushed into queue and launched one-by-one.

Of course there should be ability to kill tasks when it has hung.

After some googling I've found two related things: [Celery](https://github.com/ask/celery#readme) and [Task Spooler](http://vicerveza.homeunix.net/~viric/soft/ts/)

Could you suggest something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider [Condor](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/) and [one of the forks of Sun Grid Engine](http://gridengine.org/blog/faq/). Both Condor and SGE are heavily used in the academic HPC community for batch scheduling, and will allow you to scale gracefully should you acquire additional hardware.

Comment: slurm is another option which is quite popular, although perhaps more targeting efficient scheduling of large MPI jobs on large clusters.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting up task queue using Celery and PyCUDA? You would be able to delegate jobs between CPUs as well as between CUDA cores.